# Android application crashing unexpectingly

Tags: java, android

Android App beginner having some issues with the application not being able to open. Just started working with it tonight. No errors shows on the code in eclipse. Just when I try to run it from the emulator is closes unexpectedly.

**Main Source**: 
    package com.example.solidshellsecurity;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = "SolidShellSecurity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void processClick(View display) {
        int id = display.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case (R.id.displayWebsite):
                Log.i(TAG, "Loading SolidShellSecurity website");
                Intent website = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.solidshellsecurity.com"));
                startActivity(website);
                break;
            case (R.id.communityDisplay):
                Log.i(TAG, "Loading SolidShellSecurity Community");
                Intent community = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.community.solidshellsecurity.com"));
                startActivity(community);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

**XML**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sssbd"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/displayWebsite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:onClick="processClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/displayWebsite"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Website" >

        <requestFocus />
    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/communityDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/displayWebsite"
        android:layout_below="@+id/displayWebsite"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="processClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/communityDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Open Community" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error Log**:

```
01-17 08:12:52.383: W/Trace(880): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-17 08:12:52.413: W/Trace(880): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-17 08:12:52.853: D/dalvikvm(880): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 7% free 2514K/2680K, paused 67ms, total 78ms
01-17 08:12:53.174: I/dalvikvm-heap(880): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.191MB for 16384016-byte allocation
01-17 08:12:53.274: D/dalvikvm(880): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 18512K/18684K, paused 96ms, total 96ms
01-17 08:12:53.393: D/dalvikvm(880): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 18512K/18684K, paused 14ms+20ms, total 119ms
01-17 08:12:54.433: D/dalvikvm(880): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 18512K/18684K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
01-17 08:12:54.433: I/dalvikvm-heap(880): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 36864016-byte allocation
01-17 08:12:54.483: D/dalvikvm(880): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 1% free 18502K/18684K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
01-17 08:12:54.483: E/dalvikvm-heap(880): Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a719a0 self=0x2a00bba8
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880):   | sysTid=880 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073849308
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880):   | state=R schedstat=( 1580552179 1052425085 177 ) utm=126 stm=32 core=0
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.483: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3257)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-17 08:12:54.493: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at com.example.solidshellsecurity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-17 08:12:54.503: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-17 08:12:54.513: I/dalvikvm(880):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.523: I/dalvikvm(880):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 08:12:54.523: I/dalvikvm(880):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-17 08:12:54.523: I/dalvikvm(880):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-17 08:12:54.523: I/dalvikvm(880):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.523: D/skia(880): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
01-17 08:12:54.533: D/AndroidRuntime(880): Shutting down VM
01-17 08:12:54.533: W/dalvikvm(880): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.solidshellsecurity/com.example.solidshellsecurity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.example.solidshellsecurity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  ... 11 more
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  ... 23 more
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3257)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Your are having Big image

```
01-17 08:12:54.563: E/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

That causing you out of memory Error 
to Scale Down Image You can Use The following Snippet

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the issue, but wasn't 100% sure. Im using a company image we put on like desktop backgrounds and tried doing it without resizing. I resize it and see if that helps.